# ¿Cómo deserializar una lista de objetos?

Tags: c#, json

```
public void Rest()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/");
    var request = new RestRequest("GetData", Method.GET);
    request.Timeout = 300000;
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddParameter("Del",btnDel.Text);
    request.AddParameter("Al", btnAl.Text);
    //request.AddParameter("llaveEmp", llaveEmp);
    request.AddParameter("id", id);
    var temp = client.Execute(request).Content;
    var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>();
    //Error en la penúltima línea
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
}
```

Me esta marcando error en la penúltima línea:

> "No overload for method DeserealizeObjet take 0 arguments"

No he utilizado `Json` casi nunca, y quisiera saber a qué se debe ese error, si le estoy pasando la lista con un tipo de objeto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este problema se debe a esta línea:

```
var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>();
```

Ya que en ninguna sobrecarga del método [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) acepta cero argumentos, dicho de otra manera, siempre se espera el método reciba uno o más argumentos dependiendo de la sobrecarga.

Para solucionar este problema, primero debes recibir la respuesta en una variable de tipo `string` y luego intentar deserializar al tipo deseado:

```
string respuesta = client.Execute(request).Content;
List<TablaVales> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>(respuesta);
```

Finalmente, el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public void Rest()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/");
    var request = new RestRequest("GetData", Method.GET);
    request.Timeout = 300000;
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddParameter("Del",btnDel.Text);
    request.AddParameter("Al", btnAl.Text);
    //request.AddParameter("llaveEmp", llaveEmp);
    request.AddParameter("id", id);
    string respuesta = client.Execute(request).Content;
    List<TablaVales> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>(respuesta);
    //Error en la penúltima línea
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
}
```